# Hide DOM content if there is an alert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Say we have - `/test?id=123` , and when we're on the respective page, there is a check occurring here, and if this check fails - there is an alert message that pops up and redirects you to `'/'`.

Right now, this works fine, except that it loads the DOM content to the `HTML` page when the URL is hit. Is there anyway I could hide the DOM content completely, if the check fails and redirects me to the index page? This basically means that if the alert message pops up, the user should not be able to see what the HTML page contains and should be redirected immediately.

Comment: Could you set the DOM content to be hidden by default and show it when there isn't an alert?

Comment: How can I achieve that using angular?

Comment: using `ng-show` and then doing a conditional to check if an alert is going to show or not, if it's not, then set the variable to true and the content will show for you. (I believe this is how it should work, not an angular expert, only dabbled.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ng-if` to wrap your sensitive DOM content, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        ...
        </header>
        <dialog ng-if="!checkPassed">This is your alert.</dialog>
        <main ng-if="checkPassed" ng-cloak>
           This is your protected content.
        </main>
        <footer>
        ...
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

`ng-cloak` will stop your content being visible at page load.
`ng-if` will remove your content from the page if the condition (in this case `$scope.checkPassed`) resolves to `false`.

In your Angular controller you would need to set the value of `$scope.checkPassed` to be `true` or `false` depending on whether your check succeeded or failed.

This is better than `ng-show` because it means someone can't code inspect your site and see the content anyway.